# Linq query conversion from Ilist<> to List<>

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I receive `IList<>` data and stores them like this:

```
 IList<Student> StudentList = DataKilde.Studenter();
```

Now I want to read them into a `List<Student>`:

```
List<Student> studentWhere3 = StudentList.Where(x=> x.StudentId > 2 && x.StudentId < 8).ToList();
```

This is working...becoz I think `.ToList` converts it to `Ilist<>` to `List<>`?

My problem is, when I am doing this:

```
List<Student> studentWhere5 = from s in StudentList
                              where s.StudentId==2
                              select s
```

I get a conversion error and have tried these:

```
from s in (List<Student>)StudentList

from s in StudentList as List<Student>
```

But it's not working.. I don't get why ?

Comment: The LINQ query returns `IEnumerable<Student>` which is not a `List<Student>`. Store it in a variable `var query = ...` then call `List<Student> studentWhere5 = query.ToList();`

Answer (score 6):

That's because `select s` returns an `IQueryable<Student>`, which is not implicitly nor explicitly convertable to a `List<Student>`, because there is no inheritance between the two.

You need to *materialize* the query result into a list:

```
(from s in StudentList
where s.StudentId==2
select s).ToList();
```

This will take all elements from the source collection (`s`) and store them in a `List<Student>`, which implements `IList<Student>`.